# What is the effect when I reduce the number of physical CPUs in a Windows Server 2008 machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, central-processing-unit

I need to reduce (remove 2 CPUs) the number of physical CPUs in one of our servers (4 CPUs to 2 CPUs). Does it have any impact on the Windows Server 2008 operating system? I mean, do we need to reinstall it or we can use it without any problem after the CPUs number reduction.

Comment: Be aware that the memory banks belonging to the now empty CPU sockets will no longer be usable either.

Comment: If you have a lot of software that runs on the server then you can certainly expect a slowdown for starters. What is the server used for?

Answer (score 0):

It will just work. Obviously it will require a restart, but removing the CPU requires a powerdown already.

Comment: @mdpc looks like an answer to me... what am I missing?